# PowerShell: Difference between array notation?

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-2.0, notation

Is there a difference between these two array creation statements? So, is '@' sign optional when creating arrays?

```
$a = "This", "Is", "a", "cat"
$a.GetType()
$a | gm
$a = @("This", "Is", "a", "cat")
$a.GetType()
$a | gm
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$a = @() # declare an empty array.

$a = @(mysingleitem) # declare an array with a single element
```

In other case is optional.

Comment: Similarly, if the results of the expression inside the array subexpression operator evaluates to null or a single item, then it will still return an array of length zero or one, respectively. E.g. `@(Get-WMIObject win32_logicalDisk)`, from [`about_Operators`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113242).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a difference between these two array creation statements?

Though I am not 100% sure (it depends on PowerShell guts) the difference may be the following: `"This", "Is", "a", "cat"` creates an array. `@("This", "Is", "a", "cat")` creates the same array and **then** applies the operator @() to it (apparently redundant operation in this particular case).

Using, for example, [this profiler](http://nightroman.wordpress.com/2006/09/20/measure-commandex-ps1-runs-measure-command-several-times/) we can see that the second expression is quite slower (14% or something), so that my guess may be correct. Ideally, PowerShell code interpretator could treat these two expressions in the same way but it probably does not.

See also the help topic (the end, about operators `@()` and `,`)

```
help about_operators
```